# How to place the text in the top right corner and not show buttons when printing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a mailing label form to be viewed in a html and printed so

How can i make it so the  that contains TO: shows at the top right corner of that td?, right now its comming in the middle like

```
    John Doe
TO: 124 test ave
    Somecity, CA 5555



TO :  John Doe
      blah blah
      blah, CA 55555
```

Related CSS:

```
 table.myLabel
        {
            width: 550px;
            margin-top: 75px;
            margin-left: 200px;
            margin-right: auto;

        }

        .myLabel td
        {
            padding: 5px;
        }
        .myLabel td.myLabel div
        {
            text-align:right;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the related html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide elements when printing, create a seperate CSS file called something like print.css and make sure its media type is print:

```
<link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" />
```

This stylesheet will now only be read when printing and can be used to override other styles. For example, to hide buttons when printing you could put:

```
input.print_button
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: No worries. Please provide some source code and may be able to help out with the other issue too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set  `vertical-align: top` ?